# Assigning two arrays by ID

Tags: java, android, loops, if-statement, kotlin

I am in stuck with easy things such a loop `for` and `if` statement.

I have two different objects:

**objectA:**

0: id = 1, name = null

1: id = 3, name = null

**objectB:**

id = 1, name = NameForID1

id = 3, name = NameForID3

**My point is to assign names from objectB to objectA by ID value.**

I've done double loop + if:

```
            for (int i = 0; i <= objectA.size() - 1; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j<=objectB.size() - 1; j++){
                    if(Objects.requireNonNull(objectA.get(i).getobjectAID()).equals(objectB.get(j).getObjectBID()))
                        objectA.get(i).setobjectAName(objectB.get(j).getobjectBName());
                }
            }
```

And after this I have a list of `objectA` with last name from `objectB` array. According to Android Studio Debugger and some... logic... this is logically, but what I am missing and doing wrong?

**My bad output:**

*objectA:*

0: id = 1, name = NameForID3

1: id = 3, name = NameForID3

**Expected output:**

*objectA:*

0: id = 1, name = NameForID1

1: id = 3, name = NameForID3

**UPD**

ObjectA class:

```
class objectA:Serializable {
    var objectAID: Int? = null
    var objectAName: String? = null
}
```

ObjectB class:

```
class objectB {

    var objectBName: String? = null
    var objectBID: Int? = null

}
```

**UPD. 30.04.2020:**
Still getting the same bad output, based on answers below have tried different variations of `equals`, `==`, `===`, POJO in Java instead of Kotlin.

***UPD:*** Just wasted your time - when I was trying to found error with your hints, I have malwared my code and started assigning equal IDs to objectA so and names were equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I am assuming that the `ids` are `integers`:**

**Try this:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < objectA.size(); i++){

for(int j = 0; j < objectB.size(); j++){

if(objectA.get(i).getobjectAID() == objectB.get(j).getObjectBID()){

//set
objectA.get(i).setobjectAName(objectB.get(j).getobjectBName());

}

}

}
```

**Your POJO must be in java like this:**

**Object A**

```
public class objectA {
    private int objectAID;
    private String objectAName;

    //generate getters and setters........
}
```

**Object B**

```
public class objectB {
    private int objectBID;
    private String objectBName;

    //generate getters and setters........
}
```

Comment: With this code it is not entering in `if` statement so I didn't get any `setobjectAName()`.

Comment: are your ids integer or string?

Comment: all ids are integer. equals statement returning me into my bad output from my post.

Comment: IDE cannot recognize operator ===, getting error "Expression expected".

Comment: you are using Kotlin?

Comment: In Kotlin I wrote only POJO classes of objectA and objectB. Then I am using their getters and setters in Java, which are automatically generated.

Comment: I updated the whole answer you must use java objects, and `==` to compare ints.

Comment: I am always using Kotlin for objects and it works perfect with Java but yes I tried to use Java POJO (and `==`) as you said and nothing changes - still getting my bad ouput.

Comment: I have only one difference with your code - `class objectA implements Serializable` because I'm getting objectA as `extra` from another activity.